# How to turn off variable shortening in Sentry web UI exception traces?

Tags: django, debugging, exception, sentry

Sentry is shortening variables in the context of exception, I'd like to turn that shortening off or at least change the shortening rules so I would be able to see exactly what queries are causing the exception.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The truncation is done on the client side. Raven has two options describing max_length:

- **string_max_length** (default: **400**)
- **list_max_length** (default: **50**)

so to increase the maximum string length to 100000 you can instantiate the Client like this:

```
client = Client('http://public:secret@example.com/1', string_max_length=100000)
```

In Django you can pass the same option to your RAVEN_CONFIG dict in your `settings.py`:

```
RAVEN_CONFIG = {
   'dsn': 'http://public:secret@example.com/1',
   'string_max_length': 100000,
}
```

or add `SENTRY_MAX_LENGTH_STRING=100000`

the same goes to **list_max_length** (`SENTRY_MAX_LENGTH_LIST`)

Comment: As of the latest version on Github, SENTRY_MAX_LENGTH_STRING seems to be working only for Flask.